# Introduction to jacobi modular forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I'm quite interested in Eichler-Zagier theory about modular forms, but I am not clear about the requirements. I know a little algebraic geometry and a little algebraic number theory, but I would like to know references or introductive material in the subject. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article [Jacobi form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_form) has a single reference, and it is to the book *The theory of Jacobi forms* by Eichler and Zagier. You may find the information you want there.